# Javascript recursive function not returning value?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Im solving a codewars problem and im pretty sure i've got it working:

```
function digital_root(n) {
    // ...
    n = n.toString();
    if (n.length === 1) {
        return parseInt(n);
    } else {
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            //console.log(parseInt(n[i]))
            count += parseInt(n[i]);
        }
        //console.log(count);
        digital_root(count);
    }
}

console.log(digital_root(942));
```

Essentially it's supposed to find a "digital root":

> A digital root is the recursive sum of all the digits in a number.
>   Given n, take the sum of the digits of n. If that value has two
>   digits, continue reducing in this way until a single-digit number is
>   produced. This is only applicable to the natural numbers.

So im actually getting the correct answer at the end but for whatever reason on the `if` statement (which im watching the debugger run and it does enter that statement it will say the return value is the correct value.

But then it jumps out of the `if` statement and tries to return from the main `digital_root` function?

Why is this? shouldn't it break out of this when it hits the `if` statement? Im confused why it attempt to jump out of the `if` statement and then try to return nothing from `digital_root` so the return value ends up being undefined?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not returning anything inside `else`. It should be:

```
return digital_root(count);
^^^^^^^
```

**Why?**

`digital_root` is supposed to return something. If we call it with a one digit number, then the `if` section is executed, and since we return from that `if`, everything works fine. But if we provide a number composed of more than one digit then the else section get executed. Now, in the `else` section we calculate the `digital_root` of the `count` but we don't use that value (the value that should be returned). The line above could be split into two lines of code that makes it easy to understand:

```
var result = digital_root(count); // get the digital root of count (may or may not call digital_root while calculating it, it's not owr concern)
return result;                    // return the result of that so it can be used from the caller of digital_root
```

Comment: Crap, im not super used to using recursion. I guess....can you explain why we return this? Is it because your returning the value from the "future" to itself "now" i guess?

Comment: @msmith1114 Check the explanation! I hope it's useful.

Answer (score 2):

**Code review**

My remarks is code comments below

```
// javascript generally uses camelCase for function names
// so this should be digitalRoot, not digital_root
function digital_root(n) {
    // variable reassignment is generally frowned upon
    // it's somewhat silly to convert a number to a string if you're just going to parse it again
    n = n.toString();
    if (n.length === 1) {
        // you should always specify a radix when using parseInt
        return parseInt(n);
    } else {
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            //console.log(parseInt(n[i]))
            count += parseInt(n[i]);
        }
        // why are you looping above but then using recursion here?
        // missing return keyword below
        digital_root(count);
    }
}

console.log(digital_root(942));
```

**Simple recursive solution**

With some of those things in mind, let's simplify our approach to `digitalRoot`...

```js
const digitalRoot = n =>
  n < 10 ? n : digitalRoot(n % 10 + digitalRoot((n - n % 10) / 10))
  
console.log(digitalRoot(123))         //          => 6
console.log(digitalRoot(1234))        //       10 => 1
console.log(digitalRoot(12345))       //       15 => 6
console.log(digitalRoot(123456))      //       21 => 3
console.log(digitalRoot(99999999999)) // 99 => 18 => 9
```

---

**Using reduce**

> A digital root is the recursive sum of all the digits in a number. Given n, take the sum of the digits of n. If that value has two digits, continue reducing in this way until a single-digit number is produced. This is only applicable to the natural numbers.

If you are meant to use an actual reducing function, I'll show you how to do that here. First, we'll make a `toDigits` function which takes an integer, and returns an Array of its digits. Then, we'll implement `digitalRoot` by reducing those those digits using an `add` reducer initialized with the empty sum, `0`

```js
// toDigits :: Int -> [Int]
const toDigits = n =>
  n === 0 ? [] :  [...toDigits((n - n % 10) / 10), n % 10]

// add :: (Number, Number) -> Number
const add = (x,y) => x + y

// digitalRoot :: Int -> Int
const digitalRoot = n =>
  n < 10 ? n : digitalRoot(toDigits(n).reduce(add, 0))
      
console.log(digitalRoot(123))         //          => 6
console.log(digitalRoot(1234))        //       10 => 1
console.log(digitalRoot(12345))       //       15 => 6
console.log(digitalRoot(123456))      //       21 => 3
console.log(digitalRoot(99999999999)) // 99 => 18 => 9
```

Answer (score 0):

its a recursive function the code should be somewhat like this

```
function digital_root(n) {
    // ...
    n=n.toString();
    if(n.length === 1){
         return parseInt(n);
    }
    else
    {
    let count = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i<n.length;i++)
    {
    //console.log(parseInt(n[i]))
    count+=parseInt(n[i]);
    }
   //console.log(count);
   return digital_root(count);
   }
}
```

you should return the same function instead of just calling it to get the correct call stack

Comment: why are you using a loop and recursion? in this case, it's pretty much one or the other – that's beside the point anyway; your function returns `9` for `digital_root(123123123)` but should return `18`

Comment: well the question was why its returning undefined instead of a value , i just corrected recursive part portion of the code

Comment: and for your next question please see this link for what is digital root

http://www.thonky.com/nine-hours-nine-persons-nine-doors/digital-root

digital_root(123123123) = 9 and not 18 if i got the digital root concept right.if i am wrong i apologies ,please share your view on digital roots

Comment: you are correct. I have mistaken digital root as the simple sum of the digits. thank you