# Why isn't my function reducing the number to a single digit?

Tags: javascript

```
function plusD(n) {

   if (n > 9) {
      let varies = 0;
      let NewN = n.toString().split('');
      console.log(NewN)
      for (let i = 0; i < NewN.length; i++) {    
         varies = varies + parseInt(NewN[i])
      }

      if (varies > 9) {
         plusD(varies)
      }
      return varies;
   }
}
```

As you can see, in the end there is an extra if statement used , when true calls the `plusD` function again which results in another addition of the number or if false(only when the number has been successfully reduced to single digit), returns the number.

Comment: Can you give an example of input and desired output? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript recursive function not returning value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648136/javascript-recursive-function-not-returning-value)

Comment: @CalvinNunes adding all the digits of a number until the number has been reduced to a single digit.

Comment: @Ivar kind of. Why are we returning the function why cant we call it directly because at some point the function will surely return and that point is when the number is at its digital root.

Comment: @okerrrrrrrr You should see those function calls as completely separate. Your function doesn't modify anything outside of that function itself. The only thing you can use is the value it gives back. If you ignore it, the function call wont change anything. By returning it, it will pass it back to the frame that called it, which will pass it back to the frame that called it, etc...

Comment: put return before plusD(varies) in the if statement. Otherwise you are not doing anything with the result you get from recusively calling plusD and only returning the first varies you get

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `return`. Without that, the function return value will never be taken into account.

```js
function plusD(n) {

   if (n > 9) {
      let varies = 0;
      let NewN = n.toString().split('');
      console.log(NewN)
      for (let i = 0; i < NewN.length; i++) {    
         varies = varies + parseInt(NewN[i])
      }

      if (varies > 9) {
         return plusD(varies)
      }
      return varies;
   }
}

console.log(plusD(29));
```

Comment: Oh as in, take whatever you get from that function and return it outside of that scope. Which gives it to the first if statement scope and it returns varies then. Without it the value stays in the same scope as the second if statement and never gets returned

Answer (score 0):

```js
function plusD(n) {
   var varies;
   if (n > 9) {
      varies = 0;
      let NewN = n.toString().split('');      
      
      for (let i = 0; i < NewN.length; i++) {         
         varies = varies + parseInt(NewN[i])         
      }  
       
      if (varies > 9) {         
        return  plusD(varies)
      }      
   }
   return varies;
}

console.log(plusD(123456));
```