# Simple javascript function doesn't returns value

Tags: javascript, return, undefined

I wrote simple function that multiplicates until the result becomes one-digit number.
For example, when you put 1234 as parameter, the flow would be like this: (parameter: 1234) => (result: 1*2*3*4 = 24) => (parameter: 24) => (result: 2*4 = 8) => return 8.

It produces result that I expected, but it doesn't return value. When I put 1234 as a parameter, it goes through the calculation and the ending result becomes 8, but it doesn't return the result. It's strange because the the `console.log` works but the `return` doesn't work.

Why does it work like this?

```js
function multiplicativePersistence (num) {
  if (num >= 10) {
  let result = 1;
    String(num).split('').forEach((ele) => {
      result = result * Number(ele);
    })
    multiplicativePersistence(result);
  } else {
    console.log(num); // 8
    return num; // undefined
  }
}

console.log(multiplicativePersistence(1234)) // console.log says 8 but nothing is returned
```

Comment: Please don’t put code in comments. Edit the question instead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript recursive function not returning value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648136/javascript-recursive-function-not-returning-value)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return your recursively-called function:

```
function multiplicativePersistence (num) {
  if (num >= 10) {
  let result = 1;
    String(num).split('').forEach((ele) => {
      result = result * Number(ele);
    })
    return multiplicativePersistence(result); // return here
  } else {
    console.log(num); // 8
    return num; // undefined
  }
}

console.log(multiplicativePersistence(1234))
```

Comment: **OH IT WAS SO...!** Thanks for your help