# Javascript function is not returning a value even when value is defined

Tags: javascript

Ok so I feel like I'm missing something let me show you a very simple function I wrote.

```
function findClosestAncestor(html_child_element, html_class_name) {
    if (!html_child_element.parentElement.classList.contains(html_class_name)) {
        findClosestAncestor(html_child_element.parentElement, html_class_name)
    } else {
        return html_child_element.parentElement;
    }
}
```

When I am feeding in a child element from my page I debug this function and as expected it hits the else statement after running through twice. This has been confirmed via Chrome's dev tools debugging it live and is the element on the page I wish to return. However when the function is called and set to a variable like so

```
let parentPanel = findClosestAncestor(e.target, "panel");
```

parentPanel is undefined after I exit the function. This is causing me a bit of confusion and I may just be overlooking something very simple here. What is happening.

EDIT:
Per Thomas suggestion I have tested .closest() this still is not returning a value either. The relevant parts of the structure of the HTML is below

```
                                <div class="list-info">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="account-type text-title">Type</div>
                                        <div class="account-type-placeholder text-info">Type Placeholder</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="account-phone text-title">Phone</div>
                                        <div class="account-phone-placeholder text-info">Phone Placeholder</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr /> <hr />
                                    <button class="sublist-accordion">
                                        <div class="sublist-title">
                                            Other cases for this Customer
                                        </div>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="sublist-panel">
```

The element we are calling either method on is the final sublist-panel you see the top of there. It should be and in the case of my method is successfully finding the panel class above. However it is still not allowing me to assign that out as a return value and is returning undefined for both my method and .closest

Comment: You may want to add a `return` in your `if` block

Comment: `let parentPanel = e.target.closest(".panel");` [MDN Element#closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

Comment: @Thomas I do not have access to jquery.

Comment: @Iptay this is plain JS, not jquery. That's why I linked the docs for that method.

Comment: @Seblor I will later. That is again not the issue here. This is being tested in a very specific situation and as confirmed by the debugger it is successfully finding the value wanted. However it is not assigning it as parentPanel is undefined

Comment: @Thomas very well. Regardless any ideas as to why this code would not be returning a value when it is hitting the else statement

Comment: Then can you include a snippet that triggers the error and your desired behavior ?

Comment: @Iptay, it does return, just not to `let parentPanel = ...`, but to this here `ignoreReturnedValue = findClosestAncestor(html_child_element.parentElement, html_class_name)`. If you would `return findClosestAncestor(...)` and not ignore that value, it would be passed on up to the initial code that called the outermost recursion.

Comment: @Iptay Given your debugger is showing that it hits the else statement, is it also showing which iteration of findClosestAncestor hits it? If it is a secondary iteration without a return statement in the if part of the previous iteration there's no way to pass the result up the call stack to the original caller. (I would have thought).

Comment: @BenStephens Thank you. That is what is happening. Unbelievably simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested alternative:

```
function findClosestAncestor(html_child_element, html_class_name) {
    if (!html_child_element.parentElement.classList.contains(html_class_name)) {
        return findClosestAncestor(html_child_element.parentElement, html_class_name)
    } else return html_child_element.parentElement;
}
```

The point is that you *always* need to return *something*; regardless of which branch you take.

Comment: Everyone seems to be caught on not answering the question. This value will return. It does return. My question is not about what will happen without a default return value but rather why when it is hitting this part of the code. As confirmed to be happening it is not returning a value
```
 } else {
            return html_child_element.parentElement;
        }
```

Comment: Dude - if you want function "findClosestAncestor()" to return a value ... and you don't explicitly return a value from all code paths ... *THEN THAT'S A BUG*!  Perhaps you've *ALSO* got another, separate problem or issue.  If so, you completely failed to describe it well enough for anybody to help you.  But from everything you said, it sounds like you simply don't understand how recursive functions "should" work, as  described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648136/)

Answer (score 1):

Since you check whether the parent doesn't contain the class `html_class_name`, it will keep executing the function until it finds one that contains it. But what happens if no parent has the class? The function keeps executing until there are no more parents to check.

What you are missing is an end to the recursive function when it doesn't find a parent!

```js
    function findClosestAncestor(html_child_element, html_class_name) {
        if(!html_child_element.parentElement){
            // What to do here? That's up to you
            // Return the parent?
            // Return the first child?
        }
        if (!html_child_element.parentElement.classList.contains(html_class_name)) {
            findClosestAncestor(html_child_element.parentElement, html_class_name)
        } else {
            return html_child_element.parentElement;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Again this has confirmed to return a value. I have debugged it live. I understand it will error if there is no return as it will eventually reach the top of the DOM.

Comment: If that's the case, you'll have to give us more info, since this does work locally.